# Search multiple tables in mySQL database

Tags: php, sql, search

I want to search mysql table and want show results from different tables.

Following is setup in tables,

First table is "user_initials":

```
User      Pic
Kashif   images/kashif.jpg
Asif     images/asif.jpg
```

Second Table is "user_data":

```
User     user_id
Kashif   155
Asif     156
```

I have made query to search keywords from User_initials "user" field.
But I want to show results as:
If I search kashif, result should be `kashif 155`

**What should be the query?**

Comment: sounds like you just need to add  a standard join

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. but I need query Dagon

Comment: this is not a write me the code for me free service, we help, but you have to help yourself also

Comment: i have made $query = "SELECT * FROM user_initials WHERE user LIKE '%$searchlink%'";

Comment: but i want to add user id at the end of search results. e.g Kashif 115. how i could?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join

```
select *
from user_initials
inner join user_data on user_initials.user = user_data.user
where user_data.user = 'kashif'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_data.user, ' ', user_data.user_id) 
FROM user_initials 
LEFT JOIN user_data ON user_initials.user = user_data.user 
WHERE user_data.user = 'kashif'
```